# Tamaño de imagen en HTML con bootstrap

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

El problema es que la imagen tiene un sobresaliente de mas, la imagen debería llegar hasta donde termina el menú... Esta hecho en bootstrap y ambas cosas, el menu como la imagen están ocupando 12 columnas y ya e intentado modificar el ancho de la imagen pero no ocurre nada!  [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```css
.bg-personal {
  background-image: url(../img/cookie-547636_1280.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<div class="row bg-personal">
  <div class="col-12 col-md-6 bg-transparente">

    <div class="col-md-4 d-none d-md-block ml-6">
      <img src="img/logo.png" width="350" class="my-4">

    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 d-md-none justify-content-center">
      <img src="img/logo.png" width="350" class="my-4">

    </div>


    <div class="col-12 col-md-12 text-center d-none d-md-block mr-auto">
      <h1 class="font-josefin-nombre ">CUPCAKES WORLD</h1>
      <p class="text-center font-descripcion">~La Mejor Pasteleria de la ciudad~</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-12 col-md-6 d-md-none mx-auto">
      <h1 class="font-josefin-nombre-sm text-center">CUPCAKES WORLD</h1>
      <p class="text-center font-descripcion">~La Mejor Pasteleria de la ciudad~</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="link-menus col-12 col-md-6 bg-transparente text-center">
    <p class="font-descripcion-slogan mx-5 my-2">Mas de 20 años horneando distintas variedades de postres con la mejor calidad y precio de la ciudad.
    </p>
    <a href="menu.html" class="mt-3">VER MENU</a>
    <p>-----------------------------</p>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: habría que ver el html, probaste ponerla como background?

Comment: Esta hecha como background!

Comment: Quizás, si nos pusieras el HTML y los CSS que están afectando a la captura de pantalla que nos muestras, podríamos ayudarte más fácilmente. Un saludo.

Comment: Dame 1 min para publicarlo!

Comment: Creo que se te ha cortado el HTML que trataste de publicar.

Comment: bootstrap 4? tamaño de `logo.png` (el ancho parece ser 350 cual sería el alto) ? faltaría ver el resto del html (el contenedor de la row y el navbar de abajo) pareciera que los margin y padding están empujando hacia afuera y de ahi que crezca la imagen junto con el row

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suponiendo que la imagen que se te desconfigura de tamaño es solo la que está en background y que todo lo que se ve es texto, imagenes y enlaces html independientes de dicha imagen de background.

Te paso un enlace con una base simple para guiarte en el alineado de los componentes: [enlace](https://jsfiddle.net/bdchyvf6/44/)

Te lo pongo aquí también para que lo veas mas facil:

### HTML

```
<header>
<div class="container ">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col bg-personal">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col">
            <p>CUPCAKES WORLD</p> 
            <p>~La Mejor Pasteleria de la ciudad~</p>
          </div>
          <div class="col">
            <p> Mas de 20 años horneando distintas variedades de postres con la mejor calidad y precio de la ciudad.</p>
            <p><a href="#">VER MENU</a></p>
          </div>
         </div>
         </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col bg-red">
        <span>Ejemplo de menu</span>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
</header>
```

### CSS

```
.bg-red{
  height:50px!important;
  background-color: #000;
  color: #fff;
}

.bg-personal{
  width: 100%;
  height: 150px;
  background-color: #ff00ff; /*Tu IMAGEN*/
}
```